# Memory Leak in PDFKit with this trivial code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdfkit

Executing this trivial code on a PDF File

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"/Users/pc/Desktop/C# 4.0 in a Nutshell The Definitive Reference.pdf"];
    PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [document release];

}
```

and running it with **instrument** I obtain a memory leak as the following

[image]

After investigating a bit I saw it happens only for some PDF Files. Other files run without any leak warning in Instrument.

Is this a bug in PDFKit ?

**Update**

This code executed several time rises seriously memory

```
-(IBAction) test: (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Starting");
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"/Users/pc/Desktop/C# 4.0 in a Nutshell The Definitive Reference.pdf"];

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [document release];
        [pool release];
    }

    [pool release];


}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to file a bug in Radar.

Answer (score 2):

Does the leak amount increase with each PDF opened? If so, then you would want to file a bug via Radar at https://bugreport.apple.com/

If the amount stays constant no matter how many PDFs are opened, it's probably not a bug.